# Custom Post Type, limit to one

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm using custom post types for a few pages where I have a very customized template...but I only need one of each post (maybe not the best way to go about this...but it's built so I'd like to not have to change this).

Is there a way to remove the "Add New" link on the **left side admin menu** just so the user doesn't keep making more than 1 version of this post?

I'm okay with the "Add new" inside the actual page as that seems a bit harder to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the 'Add new' submenu page like so:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myprefix_adjust_the_wp_menu', 999 );
function myprefix_adjust_the_wp_menu() {
  //Get user id
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_id = $current_user->ID;

  //Get number of posts authored by user
  $args = array('post_type' =>'myposttype','author'=>$user_id,'fields'>'ids');
  $count = count(get_posts($args));

  //Conditionally remove link:
  if($count>1)
       $page = remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=myposttype', 'post-new.php?post_type=myposttype' );
}
```

A similar logic can be used to conditionally redirect users from the 'add new' page if they have already created a post.

This method would also support querying by post status (i.e. they can only have at most one *published* post).

Of course, the above only removes the link to the 'add new' page - it doesn't actually stop them creating posts. Depending on what you are after, you could remove the 'publish post' capability when they have more than 1 post (they will still see the add new link, and could create drafts but they won't be able to *publish*). If you do this you'll need to add the capability back when they 'unpublish' their post.